# A Map related error in flutter which happens everytime I try to parse it

Tags: flutter, api, hashmap, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have a map which contains two standard key and value pairs like

```
_body = {
          "expected_time": "$Time",
          "payment": "$payment",
          "receiver" : {},
};
```

And another map named receiver inside it as you can see. Values are being passed to the receiver later using a for loop and the information is being added just fine.

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
  _body['receiver'][i] = {

            "receiver_name" : "abc",
};
}
```

The issue I'm facing is when trying to send this map to an api call via http.post
there jsonEncode(body) has been used to encode the map to send it. When sending those simple key value pairs I'm getting no error but when I'm trying to include the receiver field as well I'm getting the error.

Can anyone please tell me what I need to here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not making it in the right way, try this

```
var _body = {
 "expected_time": "time",
 "payment": "payment",
 "receiver" : {},
};

for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
 _body.addAll({
  'receiver[$i]': {
    "receiver_name": "abc",
  }
 });
}
print(_body);
```

and the output is like this

```
{expected_time: time, payment: payment, receiver: {}, receiver[0]: {receiver_name: abc}, receiver[1]: {receiver_name: abc}, receiver[2]: {receiver_name: abc}, receiver[3]: {receiver_name: abc}}
```

you can now encode it

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right.  I haven't tried it in the api call yet but I tried  print(jsonEncode(_body))  and that's no longer throwing an error.